# How to display text on omnet++ sequence chart Axis

Tags: charts, omnet++, inet

How can I display text/color on the axis inside sequence chart. Something like this INET example (I mean text shows state of MAC):

[image]

I've read omnet++ manual and searched Internet but there is no informative manual to show methods of visualization in the tool

Comment: I've found a clue in omnet's user guide (not in simulation manual), Release 6.0 section section _8.3.8 Displaying Module State on Axes_. Text on axis is provided as _output vector file_ and should be attached in IDE (in sequence chart window)

Answer (score 1):

Displaying text in sequence chart can be done by creating a `cOutVector`.
Here is a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class SampleChart : public cSimpleModule
{
  private:
    cOutVector textState;
    cMessage* call_event;
    int state;
  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(SampleChart);

void SampleChart::initialize()
{
    textState.setName("moduleState");
    auto en = cEnum("state", "INITIAL", 0, "OPERATION", 1, "IDLE", 2, "DONE", 3, nullptr);
    textState.setEnum(&en);
    state = 0;

    call_event = new cMessage();

    scheduleAfter(1.0, call_event);
}

void SampleChart::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    textState.record((state % 4));
    state++;

    if (state<10)
    {
        scheduleAfter(state, call_event);
    } else {
        delete msg;
    }
}
```

How to display:

1. Open generated `.elog`
2. Select module axis and then right click and from context select `Axis...` | `Attach vector ...`
3. Select generated vector file `SampleChart-#0.vec`

[image]